# Element not taking up children's width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<pre>` and I put some content in it, in which it might be longer than the window's width. I was expecting `<pre>` will take up the width of its children, but however it doesn't seem to be the case. The `<pre>` is applying the width of the window instead of the content inside.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/d6Avv/1/

From what I know, `<pre>` seems to have `width: 100%` default value, which causes this issue.

[image]

I am looking for any solution to this problem. However, CSS-only solutions are more preferable.

Comment: It's bumping up to its parent. Set your body width to 100%.

Comment: @Malk - This will make the body to have a 100% width, relative to the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work based on whatever content you have around it, but setting

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the `pre` caused the `pre`'s width to match its contents.

---

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6Avv/10/)

In this fiddle, I added a `div` to wrap the `pre`, which should prevent the `inline-block` from messing up any layout around it, since the `div` should be `display: block;`.

Comment: You could also consider using `overflow: scroll-x;` in order to put a scroll bar on the `pre`, depending on what exactly you have to do with the data. This would prevent the user from having to scroll all of the content left and right to see the code in the `pre`. Just another suggestion.

Comment: Actually I do want the user (which is me) to scroll since a Piscal's Triangle is really impossible to fit in the window as the level goes higher. I tweaked it a little bit and here's my result: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/d6Avv/show/

Comment: I meant that if you were including the triangle in a page with a bunch of other content, then you could make it so only the part with the triangle had the scroll bar. The triangle would still scroll, just not the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
white-space: normal;
```

to the `pre`'s style.

Default user-agent style for this element is `white-space: nowrap;` which will break lines explicitely only on line breaks, thus widening the whole element.

Comment: This wraps the line which is not what I wanted.

Comment: I use `<pre>` is because I don't want line break. In my example I am trying to present a Pascal's Triangle, which line break is not desired.